# Execute NuGet PowerShell Command by code

Tags: powershell, nuget, visual-studio-extensions

I have a NuGet package with PowerShell commands.

I want to manage it from a context menu (added with a vsix). With NuGet.VisualStudio I can install my NuGet package by code but I don’t find how to execute NuGet package PowerShell commands.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Matthieu

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IScriptExecutor to execute a powershell script in your NuGet package.

Comment: Sounds exactly what I need. Thank you so much!
However, I'm not sure about the way to use it. 

For example, in my NuGet PowerShell psm1 I have 
function Foo1($param1)
{
}
Export-ModuleMember Foo1
function Foo2($param1, $param2)
{
}
Export-ModuleMember Foo2

How to call 
Foo2 "p1" "p2"
using scriptExecutor.ExecuteScript method?

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Looks I misunderstood your question. IScriptExecutor can be used to execute a powershell script file **which is in** a NuGet package. While in your case, you want to execute an arbitrary powershell script. If that is what you want to do, then sorry, this is not supported by NuGet.